# Android Studio: System UI Not Responding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

I recently migrated one of my Android studio projects from my last Dell laptop. I'm currently using an HP laptop with an AMD processor and whenever I try to start my emulator (Pixel 2 API 29) for my project, I get a different wacky virtualization-related error EVERY TIME.

Some examples of my previous errors are

> Your CPU does not support the required feature (VT-x or SVM),

> ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems,

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.

Error shown in emulator today:

> System UI not responding

I have already enabled Virtualization in my BIOS setting, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your pc doesn't meet these requirements:

> Windows
>
> Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit) The Android
>   Emulator only supports 64-bit Windows (learn more).
>
> 4 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
>
> 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and
>   emulator system image)
>
> 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio (bottom of the page)